# GIMP not working after updating to 11.10

Tags: gimp

I just updated to 11.10 and GIMP is not working anymore. Here is the error:

```
    (gimp:1689): GLib-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.30.0/./glib/goption.c:2168:  
ignoring no-arg, optional-arg or filename flags (8) on option of type 0
```

Any idea how to solve the problem ?

Comment: That's not an error, but a warning. SO it shouldn't stop GIMP from running. Start GIMP and give us the output of `px aux`, please. Because I think it's running, but the window just doesn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

You'll possibly find that you have another instance of GIMP already open with a file sufficiently large that you've put the process to sleep.

At least that's what I encountered.

1. Launched gimp
2. Received warning as above.
3. Ran ps, discovered a sleeping gimp
4. Killed sleeping gimp
5. Relaunched gimp, warning reappears, but so does gimp as it should.

lev@isocracy:~/Desktop/webdev$ gimp
(gimp:25974): GLib-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.30.0/./glib/goption.c:2168: 
ignoring no-arg, optional-arg or filename flags (8) on option of type 0

lev@isocracy:~/Desktop/webdev$ ps afux | grep gimp
lev      21142  0.0  1.5 164356 32372 ?        Sl   Dec05   0:26 gimp-2.6 /home/lev/Desktop/newwebsitevpac.svg
lev      25976  0.0  0.0   4188   776 pts/2    S+   15:08   0:00      _ grep gimp

lev@isocracy:~/Desktop/webdev$ kill 21142

lev@isocracy:~/Desktop/webdev$ gimp &
[1] 25982

lev@isocracy:~/Desktop/webdev$ 
(gimp:25982): GLib-WARNING **: /build/buildd/glib2.0-2.30.0/./glib/goption.c:2168: ignoring no-arg, optional-arg or filename flags (8) on option of type 0